# Connect to MSSQL Contained Database with python on Ubuntu?

Tags: python-2.7, sql-server-2012, ubuntu-14.04, freetds

I'm running an Ubuntu 14.04.1 86_x64 server, and I've been trying to figure out how to connect to a MSSQL 2012 [Contained Database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929071(v=sql.110).aspx). I've been trying with pymssql 2.1.0 which uses the FreeTDS driver. Based on the pymssql website I've determined that the problem is with the FreeTDS driver.

I've used `tsql -H SERVER -p PORT -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -D DATABASE` and I get the error:

> Msg 18456 (severity 14, state 1) from SERVER Line 1:
>
> ```
> "Login failed for user 'USERNAME'."
> ```
>
> Error 20002 (severity 9):
>
> ```
> Adaptive Server connection failed
> ```
>
> There was a problem connecting to the server

I don't have the same problem connecting to a MSSQL 2008 database, which does not support contained databases. Also, I have no control over that setting on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that pymssql 2.1.1 fixes this as part of their 'Compatibility with Azure'.

The code that fixes it was in lines 606-613 in _mssql.pyx, which can be found on github. I've put the lines here just for reference.

```
# Put the DB name in the login LOGINREC because it helps with connections to Azure
if database:
    if FREETDS_SUPPORTS_DBSETLDBNAME:
        dbname_bytes = database.encode('ascii')
        dbname_cstr = dbname_bytes
        DBSETLDBNAME(login, dbname_cstr)
    else:
        log("_mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__(): Warning: This version of FreeTDS doesn't support selecting the DB name when setting up the connection. This will keep connections to Azure from working.")
```